# Securing Magento Cache folder

Tags: magento

We're using Magento to power our ecommerce store. Although it's a heavy application, it is working out pretty well for us with its rich features.

One security issues we're facing with it is the cache folder that is set to 777 and very frequently attackers drop scritps and recently a bot was deployed thru this channel.

We tried moving this to a folder outside the document root, but had no luck. Has anyone tried this or any better ways to secure php-writable cache folders? Let me know.

Comment: In general all files should be `644` and all folders should be `755` and should be owned by the user your web server runs under. The mage executable should be given `550` permissions to allow execution

Comment: Must be on a shared server for this to happen.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy How does one go about setting folders to 755 and files to 644? Does 755 allow PHP to write to a folder? Any more insights?